# Check for email duplication in two different devise models. Maybe override controller methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am having two different devise models. I am wondering, how can I make sure that both the tables dont have the same email? Any help in this direction is appreciated.

I was thinking maybe I could override the controller methods, but ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Uniqueness constraint, I am afraid, works for the confining model and it's attributes scope. I still went through the API to check if some alternative exists; but couldn't find any.

Based on this, I think, you should write your own custom validation method for that.

```
validate :email, :with_user_emails
def with_user_emails
  if User.pluck(:email).any? { |user_email| user_email.eql? email.downcase }
    errors.add(:email, "Same email id present in User database")
  end
end
```

I know that this is **definitely** bad in performance and not optimized. Would love to see the good solution by experts :)

Comment: Thanks for showing me the way. I think i can tweak it a little more to fit my needs accordingly. But yes open to other solutions

Comment: yes. `User.pluck(:email)` will run a single query on database `Select email from users`, but comparison of this array's elements against a string can be a drop on performance. Also, checkout how Rails implements [uniquness](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb), if you are interested. :) It uses AREL and tries to insert the record, if that record exists, it appends error. Sweet